# Why are "they and don't" used here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The song "Sing for the moment" by Eminem.

> Idolize *they* favorite rappers and know all *they* songs

The song "Scars to your beautiful" by Alessia Cara.

> She *don't* see her perfect, she *don't* understand she's worth it

So, my point is why are those forms used here and in many songs? I saw other words that are irregular. Is that only because they would sound nice in songs?
Can we use them in everyday speech?

Comment: Those usages are examples of what has been labeled AAVE.  https://www.hawaii.edu/satocenter/langnet/definitions/aave.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English

Comment: These are non-standard and shouldn't be used in formal writing.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo you should probably post that as an actual answer rather than a comment; it is, after all, the correct explanation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because whereas "ungrammatical" colloquial usages such as *She **don't** know **them** songs* are fairly widespread among most Anglophone communities (instead of *She **doesn't** know **those** songs*), the cited use of ***they*** for ***those*** is almost exclusively an AAVE feature that learners should almost certainly avoid. Imho this makes the question far too vague and broad-based

Comment: @Darael:  I'm expecting the question to be closed. "Why" is off-topic, and the answer to "Can we use them in everyday speech?" would be opinionated, and again off-topic.

Comment: There are *many* songs that use ungrammatical constructions—or even completely nonsensical sounds that have no relation to English.